# Hover effect doesn't support for both p and h1 tags

Tags: css, html

Snippet:

```css
#Check:hover+p,
h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="Check">Test Me</button>
<p>Color will be changed to yellow</p>
<h1>Color will be changed to yellow</h1>
```

Can you please clarify where i went wrong?

Comment: That's not the way comma separation works in CSS selectors

Answer (score 1):

The `,` applies to entire simple selectors.  Your selector is parsed as `#Check:hover + p` *or* `h1`.

You need to repeat the `#Check:hover +` part after the comma.

Comment: According to my CSS code, h1 tag is already colored in yellow. it seems CSS part doesn't give any effect for that one. How can I edit my CSS part to give an effect for both <p> and <h1> tags simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```css
#Check:hover+p, #Check:hover+p+h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="Check">Test Me</button>
<p>Color will be changed to yellow</p>
<h1>Color will be changed to yellow</h1>
```

You need to add `#Check:hover` as well, and then, in order to find the desired `h1` you need to show the code its way. If you just add `#Check:hover+h1` it thinks it is the first element after the button.

So in order to do it you need to add `#Check:hover+p+h1` to tell the code the path, the first element `+p` and then the second element `+h1`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome @ThushanSamarawickrama , I am glad I could help. Please accept the answer if you feel that this is what you were looking for :).